# How to add item to disposable Observable list using RxAndroid/ Retrofit

Tags: android, observable, retrofit, rx-java2, rx-android

I am making a call to an API and returning a list of custom objects (`Observable<ArrayList<Pin>>`). Before I send the list back to the subscriber, I want to add an object I am creating locally and separately from the API call. Here is my code:

```
        val requestInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(context.resources.getString(R.string.ulr_pins))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build().create(PinsService::class.java)

        disposable.add(requestInterface.getPins()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            //How do I add a custom Pin object to the list retrieved in requestInterface.getPins before I send it to the callback?
            .subscribe(callback))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map` operation, you can convert your data to anything by `map`:

```
disposable.add(requestInterface.getPins()
        .map{ it ->
            it.add(customPinObject)
            it
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(callback))
```

Comment: I am using CompositeDisposable and that doesn't have a map function

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, does requestInterface.getPins() return a disposable? If so, you can use `map` in requestInterface.getPins() and I've updated my answer.